# How many natural products are there in existence?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, chemical-biology, drugs

Hi I'm doing a project on natural products and I'm wondering if somewhere there is at least an estimated number of how many exist?

If this exists somewhere can you please provide a reference.

Please and Thank you! :)

Comment: Depending on what you call a product, the estimates will vary wildly.

Comment: What I would do is to search for the capacity of the largest database for the natural products fulfilling your definition of them. For instance, [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26009974) is an outdated (2015) review covering databases from the structural data to some ancient Chinese recipes. On average, there is probably about 50000 or so chemical substances characterized (I might be entirely wrong, not my field).

Comment: @Bianca this article gives the number of known natural products and tries to provide an estimate of the number of possible ones (though keep in mind Ivan's point about the definition of product). They come up with a value on the order of 50 million. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3447393/

Comment: Would we count DNA strands from different individuals from different species as different "products"?